# Clojure: why is sniptest producing LazySeq

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences, enlive

I'm creating a template in enlive and having trouble with this snippet which produces lazyseq. When I try this sniptest in REPL it produces "clojure.lang.LazySeq@ba6da9f2".

```
    (h/sniptest (template-div) 
     [:div.Row]  (h/content (map #(value-cell %) 
     (for [e(:data-content msh-contents)] 
      (vals e)))))
```

The rest of the code needed to test this looks like this

```
    (require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as h])

    (def msh-contents {:title "Events mashup",
                      :data-content [{:title "ICTM Study Group ",  
                                    :url "http://some-url.com"} 
                                    {:title "Volodja Balzalorsky - Hinko Haas",
                                    :url "http://some- other-url.com"}
                                    ]})

    (defn template-div[] (h/html-resource "index.html"))

    (h/defsnippet value-cell (template-div) 
                             [:div.Row :div.Cell] [value]
                             (h/content value))
```

The index.html file looks something like this (it can also be found here http://www.filedropper.com/index_25))

```
    <div class="Table">
    <div class="Title">
    <p>This is a Table</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Heading 1</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 1 Column 1</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I saw a similar question, but the solution was to use content instead of html-content. Not sure what causes the issue here...

Comment: The improper indentation is really demotivating.

Comment: @A.Webb I changed indentations, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/wiki/Getting-started

```
x=> (sniptest "<html><body><span>Hello </span>" 
      [:span] (append "World"))
"<html><body><span>Hello World</span></body></html>"
```

From `html-resource` docstring: `"Loads an HTML resource, returns a seq of nodes."`

Notice how in the example the source is in the form of a html string and not a `seq of nodes`. Why it works the way it does beats me but you'll probably want the following:

```
(h/sniptest (clojure.string/join (h/emit* (template-div))) ; this feeds it a html str instead 
 [:div.Row]  (h/content (map #(value-cell %) 
 (for [e(:data-content msh-contents)] 
  (vals e)))))
```

PS: What are you using sniptest for because I was unaware it existed until now. Then again I use enlive in an odd way(no deftemplates or defsnippets, use of hiccup style html, and heavy use of macros).

Comment: I used it to try a snippet, because my deftemplate doesn't work, because the snippet produced LazySeq. This does work, but my deftemplate still doesn't :(

Comment: if you have time you can see the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727208/clojure-enlive-deftemplate-cant-use-snippet