# Clojure: enlive deftemplate can't use snippet

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to create template that produces table with some data in it. Data comes from a map defined in msh-contents.

```
   (require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

   (def msh-contents {:title "Events mashup",
                  :data-content [{:title "ICTM Study Group ",  
                                :url "http://some-url.com"} 
                                {:title "Volodja Balzalorsky - Hinko Haas",
                                :url "http://some- other-url.com"}
                                ]})

   ;; define snippets based on some divs in the template
    (html/defsnippet header-cell (template-div) [:div.Heading :div.Cell][value]
    (html/content value))

   (html/defsnippet value-cell (template-div) [:div.Row :div.Cell] [value]
   (html/content value))

   ;; define a template
   (html/deftemplate mshp "index.html" [cont]
   [:div.Heading] 
   (html/content (for [c (keys (first (:data-content cont)))] (header-cell (name c))))
   [:div.Row] 
   (html/content (map #(value-cell %) (for[e (:data-content cont)] (vals e)))))
```

So, callling the template in REPL

```
   (mshp msh-contents)
```

Produces error: IllegalArgumentException ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437), and its probably because snippets produces LazySeq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be really dumb, but the code works perfectly fine for me. The only difference I made was represent your html as hiccup notation then converting to nodes which is equivalent to just giving it a html file(I do this because I still haven't figured out how exactly `html-resource` works and not sure where I can put the file). Working code below:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as h])

(def msh-contents {:title "Events mashup",
     :data-content [{:title "ICTM Study Group ",  
                            :url "http://some-url.com"} 
                            {:title "Volodja Balzalorsky - Hinko Haas",
                            :url "http://some- other-url.com"}]})

(defn template-div []
  (h/html [:div {:class "Table"}
                [:div {:class "Title"}
                      [:p "This is a Table"]]
                [:div {:class "Heading"}
                      [:div {:class "Cell"}
                            [:p "Heading 1"]]]
                [:div {:class "Row"}
                      [:div {:class "Cell"}
                            [:p "Row 1 Column 1"]]]]))

(defn index []
  (h/html [:html [:div {:class "Table"}
                       [:div {:class "Title"}
                             [:p "This is a Table"]]
                       [:div {:class "Heading"}
                             [:div {:class "Cell"}
                                   [:p "Heading 1"]]]
                       [:div {:class "Row"}
                             [:div {:class "Cell"}
                                   [:p "Row 1 Column 1"]]]]]))

(h/defsnippet header-cell (template-div) [:div.Heading :div.Cell] [value]
              (h/content value))

(h/defsnippet value-cell (template-div) [:div.Row :div.Cell] [value]
              (h/content value))

(h/deftemplate mshp (index) [cont]
               [:div.Heading] 
               (h/content (for [c (keys (first (:data-content cont)))] (header-cell (name c))))
               [:div.Row] 
               (h/content (map #(value-cell %) (for[e (:data-content cont)] (vals e)))))
```

Final Result:

```
(clojure.string/join (mshp msh-contents))
=> "<html><div class=\"Table\"><div class=\"Title\"><p>This is a Table</p></div><div class=\"Heading\"><div class=\"Cell\">title</div><div class=\"Cell\">url</div></div><div class=\"Row\"><div class=\"Cell\">ICTM Study Group http://some-url.com</div><div class=\"Cell\">Volodja Balzalorsky - Hinko Haashttp://some- other-url.com</div></div></div></html>"
```

Perhaps you're giving `defsnippet` a bad source when doing `(template-div)`. `defsnippet` and `deftemplate` both take nodes. When you give them a file like `"index.html"`, it converts the file into nodes.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into this. Not sure that defsnippet isn't working, because i tried it on its own, and it was fine. I have to try something with it, so it doesn't return lazy seq, but only string.

Comment: excellent, i love hiccup. it was the problem with html-resource, so the solution with hiccup is much better.